# i have project on banking system in c++. i want to withdraw amount but when i withdraw amount i cant update new amount in file in particular position

Tags: c++, file-handling

I want to withdraw amount in account xyz but when I withdraw amount I can't update new amount in file in particular position (where 1200 is written) what can i do?

This is my withdraw function.

```
void withdraw()
{
    ofstream f2("bank",ios::out  | ios :: app);
    ifstream f1("bank",ios::in |  ios :: app);

    f1.seekg(0);
    long long a_num;
    long double w_amount;

    cout << "Enter Account Number :" << endl;
    cin  >> a_num;
    Bank ac;

    while (f1 >> acc_num >> name >> acc_type >> amount){

        if(acc_num == a_num){

            int g = f1.tellg();
            cout << "Get" << g << endl;
            int p=g;
            acc_num=0;
            f2.seekp(p,ios::beg);
            cout << "Name         :" << name << endl;
            cout << "Account type :" << acc_type << endl;
            cout << "balance      :" << amount << endl;

            cout << "Enter withdraw amount : " << endl;
            cin  >> w_amount;
            amount = amount - w_amount;
            cout << "Balance :" << amount << endl;

            f2.seekp(p,ios::beg);

            f2 << amount << endl;
        }

    }
}
```

Here's what the file [looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gxkx.png):

```
bank.txt
12345678901234   xyz    savings    1200
12345678901235   pyr    current    1600
```

Comment: you cant update a particular position in a file. You need to read all, modify, write

Answer (score 0):

The problem is very basic, your file name is **bank.txt**, but you are passing the **ifstream** and **ofstream** object **ctor** just **bank**, this won't work as probably the open operation will open some other file instead,

```
ofstream f2("bank",ios::out | ios :: app); 
ifstream f1("bank",ios::in | ios :: app);
```

And secondly you cannot open the same file simultaneously, you may instead use a **fstream** object

```
fstream fp("bank.txt",ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);
```

Addressing your question, use `fp.write ()` function to write to the file, its first parameter is the pointer to the characters, second is the number of character to write to the file, so you can set the second parameter accordingly.

It may be like this:

```
char text [5] = "good";
 // do the seekp operation.
fp.write (text,5);
```

For more knowlege see this http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/write/